# org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed:

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I am trying to create a table with ComboBoxCellEditor column. When I set value that time below exception is coming.

```
import org.eclipse.jface.util.Policy;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
```

/*............*/

> public class Test {
>       public static void main(String[] args) {
>       Shell shell = new Shell();
>       shell.setText("TableViewer Example");
>       GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
>       shell.setLayout(layout);
>       Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
>       composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
>       composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
>       Table testTable = new Table(composite, SWT.BORDER);
>       testTable.setLinesVisible(true);
>       testTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
>       GridData tableData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
>       tableData.heightHint = 300;
>       testTable.setLayoutData(tableData);
>       TableViewerColumn columnViewer = null;
>       String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Laptops" };
>       TableViewer testTableViewer = new TableViewer(testTable);
>       for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
>       columnViewer = new TableViewerColumn(testTableViewer, SWT.LEFT);
>       columnViewer.getColumn().setText(columnNames[i]);
>       if (columnNames[i].equals("Name")) {
>       columnViewer.getColumn().setWidth(200);
>       } else if (columnNames[i].equals("Laptops")) {
>       columnViewer.getColumn().setWidth(300);
>       }
>       columnViewer.getColumn().setResizable(true);
>       columnViewer.getColumn().setMoveable(true);
>       columnViewer.setLabelProvider(new TestColumnLabelProvider(i));
>       }
>       testTableViewer.setContentProvider(new TestContentProvider());
>       testTableViewer.setColumnProperties(columnNames);
>       TestBean[] testBeans = new TestBean[5];
>       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
>       TestBean bean = new TestBean();
>       TableViewerColumn[] getTableViewerColumns = 
>       getTableViewerColumns(testTableViewer);
>       for (int j = 0; j < getTableViewerColumns.length; j++) {
>       getTableViewerColumns[j].setEditingSupport(new 
>       TestEditingSuport(testTableViewer, j, bean.getListOfLaptop));
>       }
>       bean.setName("Debasish" + i);
>       bean.setLaptop(bean.getListOfLaptop[i]);
>       testBeans[i] = bean;
>       }
>       testTableViewer.setInput(testBeans);
>       shell.open();
>       Display display = shell.getDisplay();
>       while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
>       if (!display.readAndDispatch())
>       display.sleep();
>       }
>       }
>       public static TableViewerColumn[] getTableViewerColumns(TableViewer 
>       tableViewer) {
>       TableColumn[] columns = tableViewer.getTable().getColumns();
>       TableViewerColumn[] viewerColumns = new TableViewerColumn[columns.length];
>       for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
>       TableColumn tableColumn = columns[i];
>       viewerColumns[i] = (TableViewerColumn) tableColumn.getData(Policy.JFACE + 
>       ".columnViewer");
>       }
>       return viewerColumns;
>       }
>       }

/*.............*/

> class TestBean {
>       private String name;
>       private String laptop;
>       public String[] getListOfLaptop = { "Acer", "HP", "Lenovo", "Dell", "Benq" 
>       };
>       //getter and setter method
>       }

/*....................*/

```
class TestEditingSuport extends EditingSupport {
private int m_column;
private CellEditor m_editor;
public TestEditingSuport(ColumnViewer viewer, int column, 
String[] listOfTestBean) {
super(viewer);
m_column = column;
// Create the correct editor based on the column index
switch (column) {
case 0:
case 1:
m_editor = new ComboBoxCellEditor(
((TableViewer) viewer).getTable(), listOfTestBean);
break;
default:
}
}
@Override
protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
    return m_editor;
}
@Override
protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
    return true;
}
@Override
protected Object getValue(Object element) {
    TestBean bean = (TestBean) element;
    Object value = null;
    switch (m_column) {
    case 0:
        value = bean.getName();
        break;
    case 1:
        value = bean.getLaptop();
        break;
    default:
}
return value;
}
@Override
protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
TestBean bean = (TestBean) element;
switch (m_column) {
case 0:
if (valueChanged(bean.getName(), (String) value)) {
bean.setName((String) value);
}
getViewer().update(bean, null);
break;
case 1:
int index = (Integer) value;
String laptop = bean.getListOfLaptop[index];
if (valueChanged(bean.getLaptop(), laptop)) {
bean.setLaptop(laptop);
}
getViewer().update(bean, null);
break;
default:
}
}
private boolean valueChanged(String previousValue, String currentValue) {
boolean changed = false;
if ((previousValue == null) && (currentValue != null)) {
changed = true;
} else if ((previousValue != null) && (currentValue != null) && (!previousValue.equals(currentValue))) {
changed = true;
}
return changed;
}
}
```

/*..............*/

```
class TestContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {
@Override
public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
return (Object[]) inputElement;
}
}
```

/*.........................*/

```
class TestColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider {
private int m_column;
public TestColumnLabelProvider(int column) {
this.m_column = column;
}
public String getText(Object element) {
String text = null;
if (element instanceof TestBean) {
TestBean testBean = (TestBean) element;
switch (m_column) {
case 0:
text = testBean.getName();
break;
case 1:
text = testBean.getLaptop();
break;
default:
}
}
return text;
}
}
```

/*......................*/

[image: Exception]

Comment: Either the combo box is null or the value you are setting is not an `Integer`. Show us a [mcve]

Comment: I am unable to add the code. ""It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.""" this error is showing when I formatted my code.

Comment: @greg-449 can you please give me your emailId I can send my code to you

Comment: @greg-449 I added my code here, please look at my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComboCellEditor` values are integer indexes in to the list of values you give it in the constructor.

Your `getValue` method of your `EditingSupport` class must return an `Integer` index in to the values list.

The `setValue` method  of your `EditingSupport` class will be given an `Integer` containing the selected index.

Comment: I have one doubt. Can you please tell me how to disabled/enabled ComboBoxCellEditor in the table?

Comment: That is a separate question. The EditingSupport class has the `canEdit` method